# Exception when connect using LDAP

Tags: c#, ldap

I am getting the following error while connecting using LDAP

> Connection.freeWriteSemaphore(-2): semaphore not owned by any thread
>    I am using the following code

```
 public static bool Authenticate(string userName, string password)
    {
        //logger.Debug("Try to connect to LDAP to authenticate user with " + userName + "/***");

        string uDN = ldapUserDN.Replace("$UID", userName);


        bool flag = false;
        LdapConnection ldapConn = new LdapConnection();
        try
        {
            ldapConn.Connect(ldapServer, int.Parse(ldapServerPort));
            ldapConn.Bind(uDN, password);
            flag = ldapConn.Bound;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //logger.Error("Exception in Authenticate():", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            ldapConn.Disconnect();
        }


        return flag;
    }
```

Comment: ii am working in mvc architecture

Comment: From [first hit on google](http://www.unidesk.com/support/kb/sync-ldap-fails-connectionfreewritesemaphore-2-semaphore-not-owned-any-thread): "Test the connection and test authentication. If the DC test fails, consider replacing the Server Address with the name of the domain instead of the name of a specific domain controller. In Active Directory, the domain will always resolve in DNS to all of the domain controllers. So you don't have to choose just one."

Comment: I need some more details

Comment: Can you highlight some more code in it

Comment: Please specify what library LdapConnection class comes from, as it's apparently not [the standard class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapconnection(v=vs.110).aspx). Are you using the Novell library?

Comment: We are using Novell.Directory.Ldap